# How to extrude in the same way a "3D" angle?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a rubber boat.
I want to extrude the edges of a cylinder in the same way they point before not only slightly up but also slitghly to the left (inwards). If I only extrude "in the same angle" it will causes the rubber boat to have a "nib" and that's not what they look like. Is it possible to extrude it following these two angles (the light blue I drawn and the orange one) without using freehand?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extrude surface keeping face angles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95476/how-to-extrude-surface-keeping-face-angles)

Comment: This might be not what you're after but you can temporarily fill in an Ngon and then extrude, normal of Ngon will be used for extrusion along face. I'd suggest also not beveling geometry on first stages of modeling, it adds geometry which might mess up sketching form of the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do, and what Mr Zak mentioned in the comments, is to create a temporary face then extrude from that.

Simply select the end edge loop, and press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face. 
Blender needs some direction to extrude along, making a face creates a face normal.

Now blender will automatically extrude along that face normal. Note that in order for this to work correctly the face must be flat.

In this gif I first extrude with no face showing that there is no auto direction. Then I undo that, create a face and extrude again, this time along the new face normal.
[image: animated gif showing how to extrude along a face normal]